# Logic behind O(n) solution for 'Maximum length sub-array having given sum'

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am unable to understand the logic behind `O(n)` solution of this classical problem- `Maximum length sub-array having given sum` (negative numbers included),

I read that it can be solved in `O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity`, but the logic behind it is still unclear to me. I have read this solution:

1. Initialize **sum = 0** and **maxLen = 0**.
2. Create a hash table having (**sum, index**) tuples.
3. For i = 0 to n - 1, perform the following steps:

   1. Accumulate arr[i] to **sum**.
   2. If sum == k, update **maxLen** = i + 1.
   3. Check whether **sum** is present in the hash table or not. If not present, then add it to the hash table as (**sum, i**) pair.
   4. Check if (**sum - k**) is present in the hash table or not. If present, then obtain index of (**sum - k**) from the hash table as **index**. Now check if maxLen < (i - index), then update **maxLen** = (i - index).
   5. Return **maxLen**.

Examples:

```
Input : arr[] = { 10, 5, 2, 7, 1, 9 }, k = 15
Output : 4 
 The sub-array is {5, 2, 7, 1}.

Input : arr[] = {-5, 8, -14, 2, 4, 12}, k = -5 
Output : 5
```

Taken from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-sub-array-sum-k/

Could someone please elaborate on the solution provided for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of a dynamic algorithm. I will adapt the algorithm in the link, as I don't think that it is written in the most helpful way.

1. Initialise `sum = 0` and `maxLen = 0`.
2. Create a hash table having `(sum, index)` tuples.
3. For `i = 0 to n-1`, perform the following steps:

   1. Set `sum = sum + arr[i]`.
   2. If `sum == k`, update `maxLen = i+1`, continue from here to next iteration.
   3. Check whether `sum` is present in the hash table or not. If not present, then add it to the hash table as `(sum, i)` pair.
   4. Check if `(sum-k)` is present in the hash table or not. If present, then obtain `(sum-k, index)` from the hash table. If `maxLen < (i-index)`, then update `maxLen = (i-index)`.
      Return `maxLen`.

If `sum == k` at case 3.3, then we know that the sub-array `[a[0],...,a[i]]` is the maximum-length sub-array whose sum is `k`. Otherwise, we continue to 3.3. If there was no sub-array until now whose sum we equal to the current `sum`, then we add `(sum, i)` to the hash table. The reason we don't overwrite existing entries will become apparent at the end.

We now continue to 3.4. If we came across a sub-array `S` whose sum was `sum - k`, then there must be pair of the form `(sum - k, index)` in the hash table. `S` is therefore the sub-array of the form `[a[0], ..., a[index]]`.

We obtain a new sub-array `[a[index + 1], ..., a[i]]` whose sum is `k` and whose length is `i - index` as follows: Remove all elements in `S` from the sub-array `[a[0], ..., a[i]]`. Its sum must be `sum - (sum - k) = k`. Now the question is whether the length of the new sub-array `i - index > maxLen`. If it is, set `maxLen = i - index`.

Now we can see why we didn't update existing entries in 3.3. We do not want to add larger arrays (greater `index`) for a given sum. This would have made `i - index` smaller.

This is a polynomial-time algorithm, as we look at each element exactly once, and the hash table accesses are also constant time.

Answer (score 4):

A sum of consecutive elements in a list can be expressed as:

$a_j + a_{j+1} + \ldots +a_k = (a_1 + \ldots + a_k) - (a_1 + \ldots + a_{j-1})$

Let's write

$S_n := a_1 + \ldots + a_n$

Then if we just go through the list calculating $S_i$ and remembering which numbers we got, we can check at each step whether there's a front part we can subtract off to get a given sum of consecutive elements.